# Why margin-left of a Block Formatting Context element cannot get a same result as margin-right of a float element?

Tags: html, css

Here is my code:

```css
.wrapper {
  border: 1px dashed red;
  overflow: auto;
  /*clear floating*/
}

.left {
  width: 120px;
  border: 5px solid #ddd;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.right {
  border: 5px solid #ddd;
  overflow: auto;
  /*make div.right become a new BFC*/
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper" id="wrapper">
  <div class="left">This is a float div, width 120px.</div>
  <div class="right">This is a div.</div>
</div>
```

why cannot I use `margin-left:20px;` in `.right` to get the same result as `margin-right:20px;` in `.left`?

I know `margin-left:150px` in `.right` can get the same result, but why div.right as a new BFC still ignore the floating div.left while div.left doesn't ignore div.right?

[`margin-left:20px` in `.right`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A6uWP.png)

[`margin-right:20px` in `.left`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VsSgf.png)

Comment: Can you please provide an image? So we can get a better picture to understand.

Comment: What is this BFC?

Comment: BFC means Block Formatting Context.

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't use flex instead of float? Just saying it's way more flexible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The relevant part of the spec is https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visuren.html#bfc-next-to-float which says:

> The border box of a table, a block-level replaced element, or an element in the normal flow that establishes a new block formatting context (such as an element with 'overflow' other than 'visible') must not overlap the margin box of any floats in the same block formatting context as the element itself. If necessary, implementations should clear the said element by placing it below any preceding floats, but may place it adjacent to such floats if there is sufficient space. They may even make the border box of said element narrower than defined by section 10.3.3. CSS2 does not define when a UA may put said element next to the float or by how much said element may become narrower.

Which gives browsers a bit of latitude in what they actually do here, but the point is, if they place the BFC next to the float, the **Border Box** of the BFC must not overlap the **Margin Box** of the float. So changing the size of the margin on the BFC won't impact on that constraint, but changing the size of the margin on the float will.

Comment: So this is a new rule: "The **Border Box** of a BFC must not overlap the **Margin Box** of a floated element."  Why there are so many tiny rules to remember in front-end? Can't it be like "Newton's laws of motion", just three laws can explain the relationship between force and motion.

Comment: *Why there are so many tiny rules to remember in front-end?* --> no need to remember them. You face them, you are surprised, you understand them and you work with them. You have no idea how many *tiny* rules you will discover next ...

Comment: @TemaniAfif But if I don't know the the deep reason behind these tiny rules, I think I may easily forget them.

Comment: No, it's not a new rule. It's been in the CSS 2.1 spec since [2007](https://www.w3.org/TR/2007/CR-CSS21-20070719/visuren.html#floats).

Answer (score 1):

The [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float) doc says :

when you float the element to left the elements comes after taken out of the normal flow of the document (though still remaining part of it). It is shifted to the left, or right, until it touches the edge of its containing box, or another floated element.

so if the right element have width of 100px

the floated element comes after it will not take any action if you give it margin lower than 100px e.g 20px because it already far enough from this point but if you give it 200px it will take action

```css
.wrapper {
  border: 1px dashed red;
  overflow: auto;
  /*clear floating*/
}

.left {
  width: 120px;
  border: 5px solid #ddd;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 20px;
}
.wrapper:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.right {
  border: 5px solid #ddd;
  overflow: auto;
  /*make div.right become a new BFC*/
  margin-left:200px; 
}
```

```html
  <div class="wrapper" id="wrapper">
      <div class="left"></div>
      <div class="right"></div>
  </div>
```