# why does paragraph included in some non-existent block?

Tags: html, css

hello can someone explain me why does the second paragraph included in some non-existent block?

[image]

first p is ok

[image]

and especially i do not understand what kind of block 236x92(1 screenshot)? nums and names are not related
[image]
[image]

css:

```
.names {
    margin-top: 5px;
    float: left;
    width: 80px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-right: 5px;
}

.nums {
    margin-top: 5px;
    float: left;
    width: 161px;
}

p {
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 10px;
    font-size: 15px;
}
```

Comment: Please make a StackSnippet of your problem along with the minimum code required to reproduce the problem.

Comment: you need to clear float, add clear:left to `p`

Comment: @TemaniAfif sorry i have another question, now margin only works for the first p. and the second is there, but it overlaps the previous divs, why? https://imgur.com/a/972Sq1V

Comment: this is due to float, you need to apply a bottom margin to float instead of a top margin to p. Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/59559477/8620333